# How come service --staus-all outputs a non-existing service?

Tags: 12.04, upstart

When I run

```
sudo service --status-all
```

It outputs

```
[ ? ]  jetty
```

but there is no such service/process running in the system.

How do I cleanup this service/process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is no such service/process running in the system

The *service name* does not have to match the *process name* as listed by tools like `ps` or `top`. Look at the file `/etc/init.d/jetty` - that's where the service script is located, probably.

Based on the service name 'jetty', I think this is an instance of [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/). I would also guess that running

```
ps aux | grep java
```

will give you some Java processes concerning this service.

[Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) is an alternative to Tomcat - a JSP servlet engine. Does that ring a bell?

To get rid of this, removing the package should do the trick:

```
sudo apt-get remove jetty
```

This will work as long as it was installed using the package management. You'll have to remove it manually if you have installed it manually.